# Do there exist distinct integers $p$ and $q$ such that $\dfrac{p}{n} = \dfrac{q}{n+1}$ for some integer $n$?

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory

Do there exist distinct integers $p$ and $q$ such that $\dfrac{p}{n} = \dfrac{q}{n+1}$ for some integer $n$, given $p$ is less than $n$ and likewise $q$ is less than $n+1$?

Assume that $\dfrac{p}{n}$ and $\dfrac{q}{n+1}$ can be rational, non-integers.

edit: changed less than inequality constraint to strictly less than.

Comment: p and q must be distinct.

Comment: The question isn't clear.  Why not take $p=n,q=n+1$?

Comment: P=n and q=n+1 works

Comment: Mmm, I'll update it and remove the equality constraint.

Comment: Since $\gcd(n,n+1)=1$ it is clear that $n$ divides $p$ and $n-1$ divides $q$ (assuming that $p,q>0$).

Comment: Can you give an example? I'm not following.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your equation can be rewritten as $\frac n{n+1}=\frac pq$, therefore the answer is yes, since $n$ and $n+1$ are necessarily coprime, the fraction $\frac n{n+1}$ is reduced (and the unique integers are the obvious $p=n$, $q=n+1$).

---

Edit: A direct consequence of the above is that the answer to the new question is no. Since the only (unique!) solution is to have $p$ and $q$ respectively *equal* to $n$ and $n+1$.

Comment: This is correct! I've updated my question so that the integers must be distinct, not necessarily unique, and constraint is now strictly less than.

Comment: @user115660 Edited.

Comment: Ah ha, interesting. By asking the wrong question, the provided answer could be used to infer the solution to the intended question. Thank you @Arnaud Mortier.

Comment: @user115660 You're welcome.